# failed: Could not create connection to database server. Attempted reconnect 3 times. Giving up

Tags: mysql, presto, mysql-connector, connector, presto-jdbc

I am trying to run mysql queries in presto-cli and I am not able to connect to mysql server. I have given the credentials correctly inside the catalog folder

Comment: Can you add --debug to your CLI and update your question? From the error provided it looks like a connectivity issue. Have you opened the relevant ports for querying?

Comment: I got following exceptions. I am trying to setup presto with mysql. mysql server is running properly.but still not able to connect


 com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException



com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure



The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.



 java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)

Comment: The error indicates that your Presto is unable to communicate with MySQL insance. Check if you are able to telnet from presto coordinator to MySQL instance

Comment: I am running both presto and mysql in my local only

Comment: Try connecting to MySQL from a SQL client and if yes make sure that MySQL catalog is configured properly.

Comment: Mysql is working properly but presto couldn't connect to it even though everything is configured correctly